# Reading file into a struct sometimes stops for no reason

Tags: c, clion

I have the following code:

```
int main() {    
    FILE *fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File Error");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        char *componentType = malloc(200);
        char *stockCode = malloc(20);
        int numberOfItems = 0;
        int price = 0;
        char *additionalInformation = malloc(20);

        int fileRead = fscanf(fp, "%[^,], %[^,], %i, %i, %[^,\r\n]", componentType, stockCode, &numberOfItems, &price,
                              additionalInformation);

        if (fileRead == EOF) {
            printf("End of file!\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("%s Read Record!\n", stockCode);

        free(componentType);
        free(stockCode); 
        free(additionalInformation);
    }

    printf("DONE!");
    fclose(fp);

}
```

The file looks like this:

```
resistor, RES_1R0, 41, 1, 1R0
resistor, RES_10R, 467, 1, 10R
resistor, RES_100R, 334, 1, 100R
resistor, RES_1K0, 500, 1, 1K0
resistor, RES_10K, 169, 1, 10K
resistor, RES_100K, 724, 1, 100K
resistor, RES_1M0, 478, 1, 1M0
diode, BY126, 118, 12
diode, BY127, 45, 12
transistor, AC125, 13, 35, PNP
transistor, AC126, 40, 37, PNP
....
```

However, when I run the code it sometimes completes like this:

```
RES_1R0 Read Record!
RES_10R Read Record!
...
CF12 Read Record!
CF13 Read Record!
Done!
```

But sometimes it stops for no reason like this:

```
RES_1R0 Read Record!
RES_10R Read Record!
...
D12 Read Record!
D13 Read
```

Each time it still returns 0.

What is the problem?

Comment: Does your real code leak memory like the example shown? Or is it just for illustration purposes? And how many lines does your input file contains - to work out how much memory you are actually allocating. For starters, check all `malloc` return values to verify whether any allocation is failing.

Comment: Yes it leaks like the example above. However I used `...` as I couldn't show all of them of course. There are 299 records!

Comment: try `%[^,\r\n]` --> `%[^,\r\n]%*c`

Comment: Also I checked if any of the strings return NULL and they aren't!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what does that do? and that didn't work either. same thing!

Comment: If `,\r\n` are present it remains remaining to affect the input of the next line.

Comment: Try insert the lines `free(componentType); free(stockCode); free(additionalInformation);` around line 20 and see if you can reproduce this issue. I tested it with 10000 entries, and i had no such problems.

Comment: I suggest you read input lines using `getline()` or `fgets()`  then parse the resulting string using `sscanf()` , `strtok()` or something else.

Comment: @DominikGebhart Tried that (updating answer). Also try it with my input: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DFC0845CCD314D06!223395&authkey=!AE9CmHSoBg-GGFw&ithint=file%2ctxt several times!

Comment: I used your input, copied it in to have 7600 lines, works fine, i think this is just an **Edit: visual** issue with your shell, can you remove the print of "adding record" and just keep the "Done" and check if you have an occurrance where it doesnt show up?

Comment: Or `tee` the output to a file, and look into the file when the terminal produced this error again. i.e. `./a.out | tee output.txt`

Comment: Note that after you read a diode line, you get 4 back from `fscanf()` and there is nothing useful in the additional information (nothing was modified). The input stops with the newline left in the buffer (because it doesn't match the comma after the second `%i`). Your next read includes the newline in the component type of the next record because you don't include a blank at the start of your format string (and scan sets `%[…]` don't skip leading space). I suggest adding a blank at the start to skip (optional) white space. However, this isn't causing your program to fail intermittently.

Comment: You should aim to make the problem reproducible.  One thing that might help is printing the data that's read rather than just 'record read'.  Does it lock up at the same point each time?  Since you're simply scanning the data, do not dynamically allocate the fields — does the program lock up?  Have you checked the file to ensure no field is too long?  Trampling out of bounds is bad.  Have you tried using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read a line…

Comment: …and then use `sscanf()` to process it.  Have you tried adding protection to the scan sets for overlong fields: `%199[^,]`, `%19[^,]`, `%19[^,\r\n]`?  These would prevent memory corruption because of overlong fields.  Have you checked that lines in the input consistently have 3 or 4 commas (`tr -cd ',\n' < data.file | uniq -c` can work for this)?  Error check every function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It can lock up on different records. (and your right, my cmake answer was just coincidental)

Comment: Why would it only sometimes lock up on same input? Doesnt make sense to me. I just ran `./a.out; while [ $? == 0 ]; do ./a.out ; done;` for 10 minutes without any issue. If you catch another "hang", open another terminal and check if the process is still running, and `echo $?` (on same shell as where you ran the program) to see the returncode it did. I guess its not running and you got 0 as it might just be a visual thing with the shell.

Comment: See also [How to use `scanf()` on multiple lines for a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254311/how-to-use-scanf-on-multiple-lines-for-a-string-in-c) — same OP, same data set, more general problem (not a direct duplicate).

Comment: Actually that was quite a different question. Same dataset yes, but the question was asking how to use `scanf` to read lines in a string. NOT why is  my code just stopping for no reason! Nonetheless I deleted that question, as I no longer need that answer.

Comment: It is clear the issue is CLion. NOT my C code!

Comment: When you say "the issue is CLion, not my C code", what does that mean?  I don't know CLion, but… When you compile and run your program on the command line, it works without stopping, you say? What happens if you run the same binary, without rebuilding it, in CLion? Does CLion run the program in a newly created terminal window — or in a window of its own creation and under its management? Have you tried adding one of the Windows-style tricks — add a `getchar()` at the end of `main()` to wait for input? Have you added a newline to `printf("DONE!\n");` — output may not appear timely otherwise.

Comment: I also note that your sample output says `Read Record!` but the format says `printf("%s Read Record!\n", stockCode);`.  Taken at reasonable face value, you are never getting a stock code read (and you omitted a leading blank in the output you quote).  Are you sure you're running the right code?  Consider adding a counter to the program, and printing the counter value in the `read record line`.  And definitely check the return value from `fscanf()` more carefully — all is not well when it returns a value 0, 1, 2 or 3, though you can live with either 4 or 5 (but initialize `additionalInfo`).

Comment: I updated the code. Forgot to also update the output. Also I'll send a screen shot tomorow of the ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question has now changed so much since I first asked it (i.e. first I thought this was a memory/ struct issue, then it became a compiler issue, then I finally figured out it was a IDE issue), therefore I decided to create a new question altogether: [Output for CLion IDE sometimes cuts off when executing a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270122/clion-output-cuts-off).

The answer for this specific question is that this is an issue with the CLion IDE. To fix this issue, compile and run the code using a terminal and the output works fine.

Thanks to @Dominik Gebhar & @Jonathan Leffler for the help!!!

Answer (score -1):

**fscanf()** returns the number of characters read or zero at end of file, while **fgetc(fp)** returns a character or EOF when end of file is reached.

You are mixing the two methods of eof detection.

Comment: "scanf() return zero at end of file". Really? The [fscanf man page says](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf): "The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached".

Comment: `fscanf()` returns the number of conversion specifications successfully processed, which number may be 0 or more; or it returns EOF if it is positioned at EOF (there is no more data in the file), or if there is an I/O error.  It does not return the number of characters read.  If the format string has 6 conversion specifications (`%s` or similar) without assignment suppression (not counting `%*s`), then look for 6 to be returned; anything fewer indicates a problem.