# Output for CLion IDE sometimes cuts off when executing a program

Tags: clion

When using CLion I have found the output sometimes cuts off.

For example when running the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    fflush(stdout); // Shouldn't be needed as each line ends with "\n"

    return 0;
}
```

**Expected Output**

The expected output is obviously the numbers 0-999 on each on a new line

**Actual Output**

After executing the code multiple times within CLion, the output often changes:

- Sometimes it executes perfectly and shows all the numbers 0-999
- Sometimes it cuts off at different points (e.g. 0-840)
- Sometimes it doesn't output anything

The return code is always 0!

**Screenshot**

[image: terminal output cuts off]

**Running the code in a terminal (i.e. not in CLion itself)**

However, the code outputs the numbers 0-999 perfectly when compiling and running the code using the terminal.

I have spent so much time on this thinking it was a problem with my code and a memory issue until I finally realised that this was just an issue with CLion.

**OS**: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Version**: 2016.1

**Build**: #CL-145.258

**Update**

A suitable workaround is to run the  code in debug mode (thanks to @olaf).

Comment: Is it possible to set a limit of the output within your IDE?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Also shouldn't the limit be consistent. And bare in mind that sometimes it outputs nothing! Sometimes it outputs to 840. Sometimes it outputs all of it!

Comment: Why the downvote. It's a perfectly worded question that demonstrates the problem with explanation and details to reproduce the problem

Comment: Have you tried putting `fflush(stdout);` inside the loop just after the printf?

Comment: Don't post text as image.

Comment: @sjsam - This shouldn't be necessary - newlines should flush stdout.

Comment: @sjsam Yep tried that as well. Same result! But flush shouldn't even be needed here as the printf ends with a "\n"

Comment: @Olaf - In this case the text is just a list of the numbers 0 to 840, followed by "Process finished..."

Comment: @Olaf But all the text that is needed to understand and replicate the problem is in the question! Just because I also added a screenshot doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Well, it is hardly readable. Anyway, there is no need to post an image. A description what happens would be much more helpful. Along with what OP has tried himself to find out (what aybout the debugger?).

Comment: The text is contradictory: "The output in the terminal sometimes cuts off" and later "... perfectly when compiling and running the code using the terminal.". Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: @Olaf There is a description of what happens. Right after the code I gave an explanation. I showed a screen shot, because it's an IDE issue. The image is also very readable if you click it and it opens in a new screen.

Comment: I for one think the screenshot substantiates the credibility of his problem because otherwise one of the first questions would be whether OP is interpreting the output correctly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : That shouldn't be necessary is the output stream is line buffered. But what if it is fully buffered? Yahya says the output is often cut off at 840

Comment: @sjsam - Yes, that's fair.  (Although if correct, a rather large bug in the IDE!)

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure you're reading the question properly. There is NO contradiction. I said that running the code on CLion sometimes cut off. But when I run it on the terminal, it runs perfectly. This is also what I have tried so far. I updated the question to improve readability. Also per your suggestion, debug mode works perfectly!

Comment: I'm with @OliverCharlesworth this is looking like a compiler bug, especially if its working fine in a regular terminal. Consider filing a report

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: This is very unlikely, as the compiler is supposedly gcc. It is more likely an error in CLion, iff it is an error at all.

Comment: @vu1p3nox I think you meant IDE bug.

Comment: I have the same problem.
CLion v2018.1.2 in windows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The consensus is that this is an IDE issue. Therefore, I have reported the bug.

A suitable workaround is to execute the code in debug mode (no breakpoint required).

I will update this question, as soon as this bug is fixed.

### Update 1

**WARNING: You should not change information in registry unless you have been asked specifically by JetBrains. Registry is not in the main menu for a reason! Use the following solution at your own risk!!!**

JetBrains have contacted me and provided a suitable solution:

1. Go to the Find Action Dialog box (CTRL+SHIFT+A)
2. Search for "Registry..."
3. Untick `run.processes.with.pty`

Should then work fine!

### Update 2

The bug has been added here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6254

Feel free to upvote it!

Comment: Please refrain from editing the IDE registry unless explicitly asked to do so by JetBrains. These properties are not in the main settings for a reason.

Comment: Yes JetBrains specifically asked me to do this!

Comment: But that won't be true for the people who come here from Google and read this answer.

Comment: The bug is marked as fixed but I'm still having it.

Comment: Yeah, I also have this problem

Comment: problem exists for me too. CLion v2018.1.2 in windows.